# In Flutter, When logged in with phone OTP, receive OTP again and go to recaptcha screen again each time. I make changes

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

Whenever I save my project or switches from light mode to dark mode, I receive OTP message that code has been sent again or go to recaptcha screen and then again I get the timeout message. Why so? when I am already logged in? Why user goes to recaptcha screen again when he is already in? Help me out.. Here is code below:-

This is first screen code from where I get the no.

```
                            child: Text("GET OTP", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            onPressed: () async {


                              if(_formKey.currentState.validate())  {

                                Map<String, dynamic> userinfo = {
                                  'countryCode': phonecode,
                                  'phone': _phoneController.text,
                                };
                                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/OTPphoneLogin', arguments: userinfo);
                              }

                            },
```

This is second screen, where user has to put OTP:-

```
      class _OTPphoneLogin extends State<OTPphoneLogin> {

   final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController _pincontroller = TextEditingController();
  final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final CollectionReference _reference =     FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");
    



  String _countryCode = '';
  String _phone = '';
  String vid;

 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();

 }

   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final dynamic _args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    _maxScreenWidth = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width <= 500) ?     MediaQuery.of(context).size.width : 500;

     print(_args);
   _phone = _args['phone'];
   _countryCode = _args['countryCode'];


   verifyNumber(_phone);

    return WillPopScope(
  //onWillPop: () async => false,
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap:() => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),

    child: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
            width: _maxScreenWidth, //how to set it to max
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, //how to set it to max
            child: SafeArea(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(

                  children: [
                    SizedBox(height: 50,),
                    Image.asset("assets/images/practicelogo.png"),
                    Padding(

                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25.0, 45.0, 25.0, 10.0),

                      child:   Text("OTP sent on:- " "\n" +_countryCode.toString()+_phone.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25,color: mRed,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),

                    ),

                    SizedBox(height: 10),

                    Padding(

                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25.0, 15.0, 25.0, 10.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        validator: _validateCode,
                        controller: _pincontroller ,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: lRed)),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: mRed ,width: 3)),

                            hintText: "Enter OTP"),
                      ),
                    ),

                    SizedBox(
                      height: 80,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25.0, 15.0, 25.0, 10.0),
                        child: ElevatedButton (
                            child: Text("Verify", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),

                            onPressed:()=>verifyPhone(_pincontroller.text.trim()),

                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                primary: mRed,
                                onPrimary: mYellow,
                                elevation: 5,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.7)
                                )
                            )

                        ),
                      ),
                    ),


                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

  }

       Future<void> verifyNumber(String mobile) async {
await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
  phoneNumber: _countryCode+mobile,

  timeout: const Duration(seconds: 60),

  verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
    try {


      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>BottomNav()));

    } on FirebaseAuthException catch(e) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: Text(e.message)));
    }
  },

  verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text(e.message)));
  },

  codeSent: (String verificationId, int resendToken)  {
    vid = verificationId;
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text("Code Sent"+verificationId)));
  },

  codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text("Timeout"+verificationId)));
  },
);
  }

      Future<void> verifyPhone(String code) async {
PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId: vid, smsCode: code);

try {

  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);

   Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>BottomNav()));

} on FirebaseAuthException catch(e) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(content: Text(e.message)));
}
  }
```

And gets this in console:-

```
      E/zzf     (30955): **Problem retrieving SafetyNet**     Token: 7: 
    W/System  (30955): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale   because its value was null.
     W/System  (30955): **A resource failed to call end.** 
    I/FirebaseAuth(30955): [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to     create service connection to fallback implementation
    W/System  (30955): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale    because its value was null.
    W/FirebaseAuth(30955): **[SmsRetrieverHelper] Timed out waiting for SMS.**
    W/System  (30955): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale      because its value was null.
    D/FirebaseAuth(30955): Notifying id token listeners    about user ( ZuaQMaw8FxZb6jeiYKzXZJRplk52 ).
 [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to fallback implementation
```

Comment: Could you provide the code that’s calling these functions?

Comment: updated. pls check.. but I don't go to this phone auth screen. and it doesn't matter on which screen I am working on, irrespective of that it goes to recaptcha screen and comes back again and even gets the message code has been sent then after 60 secs that timeout message.

Comment: Your snippet is still missing the invocation of `verifyNumber`. That’s what’s sending the OTP, if you could provide that.

Comment: pls check now..

Comment: verifyNumber(_phone) is just  above the Scaffold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you’re calling `verifyNumber` in the `build` command. This gets called every time the State `_OTPphoneLogin` updates (any time it gets re-rendered, such as when you hot reload).

You should move this to `initState` which only gets called when the State is created, and best-practice, wrap it in a login check. You can do that by checking if `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid` is null before invoking `verifyNumber`.

Comment: I moved it in the initState that time I was not getting any error but now when I try to log in again it says phoneNumber was called on null and I don't get any OTP. What to do next? If i keep veryifyNumber function in init.

Comment: @GAGANSINGH Well, two solutions. You could pass the phone number to the `StatefulWidget` rather than the `State`, then refer to `widget.phone`. Or you could still call `verifyNumber` in the `build` command, but with a logged-in check to prevent calling it again.

Comment: will you pls explain it to me little more with an example, I am not getting where to place it and what is the best suitable option, and this same error occurs when user is new and has to register account. So, I have to make changes there also as that is different screen

Comment: @GAGANSINGH You can move it back to the `build` command like you originally had it, then wrap it in an `if` condition checking if `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid` is null. If it is null they’re not logged in and `verifyPhone` should be called.

Comment: @GAGANSINGH Or, you can keep it in `initState`, passing the `phone` variable to `OTPphoneLogin` through a parameter, then reference it in `initState` as `widget.phone`, `widget` is a built-in parameter in `State` referring to the `OTPphoneLogin` that created the `State`. This is the approach I would take, but they are effectively the same.

Comment: u there, still stuck with it,  in first where you said to wrap it in if condition, I don't get any OTP and in second where in which I have to pass it through parameter I get error in route main class.

Comment: Your `if` condition should be `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232707/discussion-between-gagan-singh-and-jediburrell).